# Ionic java build error occur while building application

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am beginner in Ionic framework. I have started building an application but I occur an error like this:

```
ANDROID_HOME=/home/raheez/Android/Sdk
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre
studio
(node:1920) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle 
in your path, or install Android Studio
```

How can I solve this. somebody please help me to over come

Comment: Install Android studio

Comment: did you install just commandline sdk or android studio? also.. can you run `cordova requirements` command in your project?

Comment: yerkon already done

Comment: android studio installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Gradle on your system:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y upgrade
wget https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.7-bin.zip
sudo mkdir /opt/gradle
sudo unzip -d /opt/gradle gradle-4.7-bin.zip
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/gradle/gradle-4.7/bin
gradle -v
```

now it should work.

See https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-gradle-on-ubuntu-16-10.